# How to install qt5-default?

Tags: software-installation, qt

I would like to install "qt5-default" on Ubuntu 19.04

starting with

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

I get "qt5-default : Depends: qtbase5-dev but it is not going to be installed"

on

```
sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev
```

I get "qtbase5-dev : Depends: libvulkan-dev but it is not going to be installed"

on

```
sudo apt-get install libvulkan-dev
```

I get "libvulkan-dev : Depends: libvulkan1 (= 1.1.101.0-2) but 1.1.114.0-1~gpu18.04.1 is to be installed"

here I am not sure what to do now

This PC is running with a gtx1080ti for which I installed CUDA so I am not sure how exactly to libvulkan1 (= 1.1.101.0-2) to 1.1.114.0-1~gpu18.04.1 and when I do so if I would break anything. Also I am not sure whether my attempt to solve the problem is correct or not. I am not an experienced Ubuntu user.

@edit /etc/apt/sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20190210)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-security multiverse
# deb http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu disco main # disabled on upgrade to disco
# deb-src http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu bionic main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu bionic dev main
# deb-src http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu bionic dev
# deb-src http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu bionic main
```

in @edit /etc/apt/sources.list.d are still bionic files :

```
daniel_pavel-ubuntu-solaar-bionic.list
daniel_pavel-ubuntu-solaar-bionic.list.distUpgrade
daniel_pavel-ubuntu-solaar-bionic.list.save
dropbox.list
dropbox.list.distUpgrade
dropbox.list.save
google-chrome.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.distUpgrade
graphics-drivers-ubuntu-ppa-bionic.list.save
lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-bionic.list
lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-bionic.list.distUpgrade
lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-bionic.list.save
teamviewer.list
```

Comment: Can you post your **/etc/apt/sources.list**? I'm concerned that you mentioned installing package(s) on 19.04, but you have 18.04 package references.

Comment: yeah just upgraded my system (2 hours ago)

Comment: Do you have any bionic repos left over, maybe a PPA that you forgot about?

Comment: seems not like it (just posted the list)

Comment: OK, sources.list looks good. What about other lists in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d**? The libvulkan-dev package version you referenced comes from the Ubuntu Graphics PPA; maybe it's still pointing to the bionic files.

Comment: @ajgringo619 you are right there are still bionic files => what to do with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a higher version of libvulkan1 when on 18.04 from the ppa and didn't use ppa-purge before upgrading. So easiest is to add the ppa back for disco and update to the ppa's libvulkan1 package for 19.04 (& any other installed ppa packages) , then use ppa-purge to downgrade to disco packages. Then you should upgrade to 19.10 as 19.04 is EOL

Comment: Thank you so far, but could you please explain the steps in more detail, it is a little bit confusing for me at the moment to precisely get what to do and especially how to do it.

Comment: Or asked in detail: What ppa should I add back for disco and how exactly do I update to the ppa's libvulkan1 package? How do I find other package for which this will be necessary? (I think how to ppa-purge I will easily find on the internet).